# UWP - How to properly support multiple screen resolutions

Tags: wpf, xaml, win-universal-app, uwp, windows-10-mobile

I have just started learning programming for UWP. And I want to write an application similar to People in windows 10. And I have a problem with supporting multiple screens.

I have layout like this:

```
 <ScrollViewer Background="Black" >
        <Grid >
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="50" />
                <RowDefinition Height="200"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <TextBlock
                Text="CONTACT"
                Margin="10, 10, 10, 10"
                FontSize="25"
                Foreground="White"/>

            <Ellipse Grid.Row="1"
                     Margin="10, 20, 250, 10" >
                <Ellipse.Fill>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="Assets/64.png" />
                </Ellipse.Fill>
            </Ellipse>

            <TextBlock
                Grid.Row="2"
                Text="Name"
                FontSize="20"
                Margin="10, 0, 0, 0"
                VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                Foreground="White"/>

            <Grid 
                Grid.Row="3">
                <Grid.Background>
                    <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill"/>
                </Grid.Background>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="350" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <TextBox 
                    Grid.Column="0"
                    Margin="10, 10, 10, 10"/>

                <AppBarButton 
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    Foreground="White"
                    Icon="Edit"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"/>

            </Grid>

        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

My output on 4" and 6" [image]
Original on 4" and 6"  screen:[image]

I defined this layout on 6" screen, so i should define layout on the smallest screen or how should I do it? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

A thorough solution for your scenario is to define adaptive UI based on screen size. You can find various approaches from this [tutorial serials](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/A-Developers-Guide-to-Windows-10).

Here I can present a simple solution: Using VisualState groups which can define different layout based on different screen size. Below is a sample. You can find more on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.visualstate.aspx).

```
<Page>
    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup>
                <VisualState>
                    <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                        <!-- VisualState to be triggered when window width is >=720 effective pixels -->
                        <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="720" />
                    </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Target="myPanel.Orientation" Value="Horizontal" />
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <StackPanel x:Name="myPanel" Orientation="Vertical">
            <TextBlock x:Name="myTextBlock" MaxLines="5" Style="{ThemeResource BodyTextBlockStyle}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Please let me know if you need anything more.

Answer (score 2):

The 250 right margin is pressing your image on the first screenshot so it looks bad

```
Margin="10, 20, 250, 10"
```

Also, your TextBox width is hardcoded

```
<ColumnDefinition Width="350" />
```

You shouldn't be hardcoding values like that - use panels in a way that your UI is fluid and responsive.

Start by reading [Define layouts with XAML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt228350.aspx)

Then continue experimenting with your layout - it's the best way to learn.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to achieve that is to use RelativePanel combined with VisualStateManager.

Moreover: If you also want that to make it bigger together with resolution put it that in ViewBox. But don't hardcode Width and Height, but MaxWidth/MaxHeight can work!

```
<Viewbox>
<RelativePanel>
<!--Your controls here positioned in RelativePanel-->
</RelativePanel>
</Viewbox>
```

In RelativePanel you describe where everything should be placed and in VisualStateManager you define how this should behave according to resolution.

Check this blog post : [MSDN BLOGS UWP: New Controls (part 1 – RelativePanel)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cdndevs/archive/2015/07/06/uwp-new-controls-part-1-relativepanel.aspx)